# How to change how many list item show in category generated by file edit-tags.php

Tags: categories, plugins

It's always been a pain in the @$$ to see only 20 item in category. If i have 30, it paged on 2 pages, i hate that. If WordPress had a preference for that. So the question, Hot to list ALL the category, whatever the number... if i have 200, list them all, no paging. I inspect edit-tags.php and could not find "show_item=20" of something like that

The question, how to make edit-tags.php show 9999 item (or unlimited) of have a plugin to customize that without hacking the WP core file.

---

I think the magic is happening here, but changing 20 to 999 dont change anything

```
add_screen_option( 
    'per_page', 
    array(
        'label' => $title, 
        'default' => 20, 
        'option' => 'edit_' . $tax->name . '_per_page'
    ) 
);
```

It's for product attribute in woocommerce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is absolutely not user friendly, but i have found it - after coding and reading 10-15 pages of plugin code that does exactly that.

It is options in `Screen Options` slide-down menu (at the top of every screen).

Keep that for future reference!

Comment: May I ask you rephrase your answer? It is really hard to read.

Comment: sorry i am french, and this is my "best" shot !... sorry  !